# How can I seperate execution analysis ability and publishing reports in sonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

is there a way to allow users in SonarQube with group permissions to execute analysis but to disable accidentally publishing and overwriting the current issues.

For example, I have an automated pull request and I'd like my developers to be able to run sonarLint Intellij plugin with my set of rules but not to have the token that will allow them to publish it from sonar scanner or maven when they run testing prior to committing.

Comment: Is there a "not" missing in the first sentence?

Comment: Yes, i would like to have my developers run analysis prrior to commit without the risk that they accidently publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/)'s connected mode, which will execute most relevant rules in the profile associated with the project without updating the project in the SonarQube server.

Developers shouldn't need any special permissions to use SonarLint, so there's no need to share any user tokens at all.

Comment: But this feature will only allow scan per one file and not per project, using the SonarQube community plugin (Intellij) will again require Execution permission - so i guess that another permission state is needed?

Comment: Scan per file is deliberate. Developers will be notified of issues in the files they're working on _as they work on them_.

Comment: Yes - that's understandable. But some developers would like to have some general summary upon several files.For example, they've changed several files and they like to see the issues in them - the only way to do so is to have the "opened files" selected in dropdown.